# Bittrex API - 'Invalid Signature' with Play framework

Tags: java, rest, playframework, playframework-2.6

I'm implementing a connection to the Bittrex API using Java with Play framework.
On some of the calls to the API I'm getting an error of 'Invalid Signature'.

This is very strange because on most of the calls the signing works just fine and I've checked with other open sources and my signing function is correct. What I've noticed is that the order of the query params seems to matter. Does Play using WSRequest does something with the query params order?

This is how my code looks for example:

```
String nonce = String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis());
String urlPath = "https://bittrex.com/api/v1.1/market/selllimit?apikey=API_KEY&market=BTC-LTC&quantity=1&rate=2&nonce=" + nonce;
WSRequest request = wsClient.url(urlPath);
String signature = getMessageSignature(urlPath);
request.addHeader("apisign", signature);
request.get();
```

As I've stated, I don't think `getMessageSignature` is the problem because my signature does work most of the time. This example fails but say I would change the order of the query params, so the URL will look like this:

```
https://bittrex.com/api/v1.1/market/selllimit?market=BTC-LTC&quantity=1&apikey=API_KEY&rate=2&nonce=" + nonce;
```

Then everything work fine, and I don't get an error. I've even tried all 120 permutations of the 5 query params and only this one works. If Ii debug and take the signature with any of the 120 options and put the request in Postman then all of them work, this is why I think it has to do with the framework.

Any help will be much appreciated(can add the function of the signature if anyone needs it).

Comment: I don't see why Play would manipulate your query params. Shows us your `getMessageSignature` method

Comment: It actually does, I will post my findings soon @Anton